# How do I create grid with squares, respecting both max width AND height using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a "grid" like on the image below. I'm using React, Sass en EC6. The problem I'm facing though is:

The image shows an example of 9 rows and 9 columns, but this can be changed to (almost) anything. For example, there could be 3 rows and 10 columns, or 5 rows and 2 columns.
But I need the content to always be on the screen, aka the container has a max width and height.
[image: Grid-like display[1]]

I want the squares in the middle to always be square, while showing the content as big as possible (no fixed width and height).

If I have for example 6 columns and 2 rows, I need the squares to be the same width AND height as 100/6 of the max width.

But if I flip the numbers, and have 2 columns and 6 rows, I want the squares to be sized 100/6 of max height.

I've tried several CSS approaches, like using flexbox, but without success.

**Example:** https://codepen.io/maffekill/pen/ZNZwXz

Is there a way to solve this without using JS?

```css
.flex-container{
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.flex-row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
   
    line-height:30px;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    margin: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    height:auto;
}
.flex-item:before {
    content:'';
    float:left;
    padding-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="flex-item">1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">3</div>
      <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      <div class="flex-item">5</div>
      <div class="flex-item">6</div>
      <div class="flex-item">7</div>
      <div class="flex-item">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="flex-item">1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">3</div>
      <div class="flex-item">4</div>
      <div class="flex-item">5</div>
      <div class="flex-item">6</div>
      <div class="flex-item">7</div>
      <div class="flex-item">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This method doesn't take the height in account.

Now I know I can calculate all the widths and heights in JS, and then change to CSS accordingly, but this wouldn't be half as neat as pure CSS, plus it takes a lot of extra resources.
Is there a way to do this with pure CSS/HTML, without the use of JS?

P.S. This is my first question on stack, please feel free to comment if something is unclear ;)

Comment: For now I solved it by just making it responsive by it's width only, but i'm still looking for a answer to make it responsive by height as well. Now the user will have to scroll down when there are 2 columns, and 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
min-width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
</div>
```

You could do something like that to make it so your container is always 100% width.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but the problem is not with my container, the problem I have is with the content of it, mostly keeping the items squared in a responsive way. Any ideas on that part?